# How to intercept Thread lifecycle?

Tags: java, multithreading, lifecycle

It is possible to log when a thread is created. We need to have a custom `ThreadFactory` implementation from where all the threads will be created and from the `newThread` method we can log it. But if we need to log when the thread is destroyed and removed how can we do that?

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public enum MyThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
    INSTANCE;

    private final AtomicInteger poolNumber = new AtomicInteger(1);
    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());
    private final ThreadGroup threadGroup;
    private final AtomicInteger threadNumber = new AtomicInteger(1);
    private final String namePrefix;

    private RpiThreadFactory() {
        SecurityManager securityManager = System.getSecurityManager();
        threadGroup = (securityManager != null) ? securityManager.getThreadGroup() : Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup();
        namePrefix = "RpiPool-" + poolNumber.getAndIncrement() + "-Thread-";

    }

    public Thread newThread(Runnable runnable) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(threadGroup, runnable, namePrefix + threadNumber.getAndIncrement(), 0);
        thread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
        thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

            public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable cause) {
                logger.error(cause.getMessage(), cause);
            }
        });

        logger.debug(thread.toString() + " created.");
        return thread;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to use your own thread pool? Is there a valid case why you would need to manage your own thread pool?

Comment: What do you mean with "when the thread is ... removed"? Removed from where/what?

Comment: You could return instead return `WorkerThread extends Thread` and which has a callback to the `MyThreadFactory` when finished

Answer (score 5):

Since you are already implementing your own thread factory, one way would be to wrap your runnable into another runnable that logs when the job is started and completed. Like this:

```
 public Thread newThread(Runnable runnable) {
     Runnable wrapper = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Starting thread ...");
            try {
                runnable.run();
                System.out.println("Thread done");
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("Thread exited abnormally");
                // Log exception
            }

        }

     };
     Thread thread = new Thread(threadGroup, wrapper, namePrefix + threadNumber.getAndIncrement(), 0);
    // ...
}
```

This does not log the actual thread lifecycle but it is reliable compared to for example trusting a finalizer to log when a thread is destroyed.

Replace `System.out.println` with logging calls of your choice.

Comment: You should also probably re-throw. And log with a real logging library instead of System.out.println.

Comment: @llogiq real logging library yes, but I like to aviod additional dependencies in my answers. I disagree with re-throw, if an exception is actually thrown from the run method it will end up in the thread's exception handler. I prefer to handle it explicitly. It should be logged though.

Comment: Ok regarding logging, but you should at least handle InterruptedException correctly, see http://daniel.mitterdorfer.name/articles/2015/handling-interruptedexception/

Comment: @llogiq I have no blocking operations in this code. I don't see how handling of `InterruptedException` is relevant at all. Please elaborate.

Comment: @K Erlandsson What if runnable.run() throws InterruptedException?

Comment: @llogiq I assume you are thinking I should call `Thread.interrupt()` in that case? That could possibly be the right thing to do but in reality there shouldn't be any need for that. The exception is caught, the run method returns and the thread exits - i.e. successful interruption. After the run method is done there is nothing else I am aware of that would block and check the interrupted flag.

Comment: @llogiq besides, `Runnable.run()` can't throw `InterruptedException`. It is a checked exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Proxy on the `Runnable` and create a Thread using proxied `Runnable`, this way you have a handle to when the run method started and ended

```
public enum RpiThreadFactory {
    INSTANCE;

    private final AtomicInteger poolNumber = new AtomicInteger(1);
    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.name());
    private final ThreadGroup threadGroup;
    private final AtomicInteger threadNumber = new AtomicInteger(1);
    private final String namePrefix;

    private RpiThreadFactory() {
        SecurityManager securityManager = System.getSecurityManager();
        threadGroup = (securityManager != null) ? securityManager.getThreadGroup() : Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup();
        namePrefix = "RpiPool-" + poolNumber.getAndIncrement() + "-Thread-";
    }

    public Thread newThread(Runnable runnable) {
        Runnable proxyRunnable = (Runnable) Proxy.newProxyInstance(runnable.getClass().getClassLoader(), runnable.getClass().getInterfaces(),
            new RunnableProxy(runnable));
        Thread thread = new Thread(threadGroup, proxyRunnable, namePrefix + threadNumber.getAndIncrement(), 0);
        thread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
        thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

            public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable cause) {
            logger.fine(cause.getMessage());
            }
        });

        logger.fine(thread.toString() + " created.");
        return thread;
    }
}

class RunnableProxy implements InvocationHandler {
    private Runnable runnable;

    public RunnableProxy(Runnable runnable) {
        this.runnable = runnable;
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Proxied Runnable Started!!");
        Object object = method.invoke(runnable, args);
        System.out.println("Proxied Runnable Done!!");
        return object;
    }
}
```